# "if" statement doesn't work properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I have made a custom keyboard in my app. When user presses spacebar, this code runs:

```
NSString *lastChar = [myTextField.text substringFromIndex:[myTextField.text length] -  1];

NSLog(@"lastChar is `%@`", lastChar);

if (lastChar != @" ")
{
   NSString *currentString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", myTextField.text];
   [myTextField setText:currentString];
}
```

And I make a check, if last symbol that user used was `space`, he won't be able to use it again
(no need in my case). However, the code under the `if statement` still runing. So I've made a check with `NSLog`, and even if the last char was `space`, the code under the `if statement` executes. How does it happen? 
Can somebody point me on my foolish mistake? 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I always forget how to compare strings in Objective-C, I've already flagged the question, thank you everyone for your anwsers.

Comment: Have you tried `if (lastChar != @"  ")` ?  (Adding another space to your if statement string). If not trying `if ([lastChar isEqualToString:@" "])` with or without an additional space.

Comment: shouldn't it be [myTextField.text length] -  2 ?

Comment: This has absolutely **nothing** to do with Xcode at all.

Comment: It should be noted that the same issue will arise in C, Java, and several other languages.

Answer (score 5):

It's not the `if` statement: `NSString`s in Objective C should be compared with the `isEqualToString:` method, not with the `!=` or `==` operators, which check *reference equality*:

```
if (![lastChar isEqualToString:@" "]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> if (lastChar != @" ")

Use

```
if (![lastChar isEqualToString:@" "])
```

As `lastChar` is not a `char`, it is an `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a thousand times. You can't compare strings like that in Objective-C (and a lot of other languages too). You have to use the comparator method which is called `isEqualToString:`.

```
if (![lastChar isEqualToString:@" "]) {

}
```

Comment: If it's been asked 1000 times, why not close as a duplicate instead of answering?